# How can I make my Discord bot recognize it when it is mentioned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Im thinking about for example I have a command that gives bread and it gives bread to every user but I want to make that if someone tags the bot then it says a different message, so I made a different func for this, but unfortunately I cant figure it out how can I make my bot recognize that the user has tagged the bot or an user... Can anyone help?

```
client.on("message", function(message) {
  if (message.content === `give bread to <@${client.id}>`) {
    message.channel.send(`I cant give bread to my self...`) 
 }
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `message.mentions.users` and use `has()` with the bot's ID which would be `client.user.id` since we want the bot's User object.

```
client.on("message", function(message) {
  if (message.content.startsWith('give bread to')) {
    
    const mentions = message.mentions.users;
    if (mentions.has(client.user.id)) {
       return message.channel.send(`I cant give bread to my self...`)
    } else {
       // Your code
    }
  }
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `client` object does not have an `id` property. I believe you're referring to the `user` object property of `client`, that returns a User object, from which you can get the client's id from.

A much more optimized route for doing your desired outcome is to check if the mentioned user (in your original function)'s ID is equal to the client id, and if so return a different output:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(`give bread to `) return
  const mentioned = message.mentions.users.first()
  if (!mentioned) return
  if (mentioned.id === client.user.id) return message.channel.send(`I cant give bread to my self...`)
})
```